# Move duplicates rows above

Tags: excel, vba

I have sheet1 and sheet10 to run a macro to find duplicates comparing column A and B.
Highlight color duplicates, in column A, move duplicates to first row A1.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any help will appreciate, thank you in advance.

Macro need to run in sheet 1 and sheet 10 maybe less sheets.

```
Sub sbFindDuplicatesInColumn()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim matchFoundIndex As Long
    Dim iCntr As Long
    lastRow = Range("A1:C").End(xlUp).Row

    For iCntr = 1 To lastRow
    If Cells(iCntr, 1) <> "" Then
        matchFoundIndex = WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(iCntr, 1), Range("A1:A" & lastRow), 0)
        If iCntr <> matchFoundIndex Then
            Cells(iCntr, 2) = "Duplicate" 
       End If
    End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: It looks to me like you forgot to ask a question. Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a range of the duplicate cells using [Union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.union), copy and insert them in the first row and then delete them.

```vb
Sub sbFindDuplicatesInColumn2()

    Const DUP_COLOR = &H9696FF  ' pink
    
    Dim ws, rngDup As Range, c As Range
    Dim arC, v, sht, lastRow As Long, n As Long
    
    For Each sht In Array("Sheet1", "Sheet10")
        Set ws = Sheets(sht)
        n = 0
        With ws
           
            .Cells.ClearFormats
            
            lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
            arC = .Range("C1:C" & lastRow) ' array
        
            lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            For Each c In .Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
                v = Application.Match(c.Value2, arC, 0)
                If Not IsError(v) Then
                
                    .Cells(v, "C").Interior.Color = DUP_COLOR
                    If n = 0 Then
                        Set rngDup = c
                    Else
                        Set rngDup = Application.Union(rngDup, c)
                    End If
                    n = n + 1
                   
                End If
            Next
            
            ' move cells and sort
            If n > 0 Then
                ' copy to top
                .Range("A1").Resize(n).Insert shift:=xlDown
                rngDup.Copy .Range("A1")
                 .Range("A1:A" & n).Interior.Color = DUP_COLOR
                ' delete
                rngDup.Delete shift:=xlUp
                ' sort
                With .Sort
                    .SetRange ws.Range("A1:A" & n)
                    .Header = xlNo
                    .MatchCase = False
                    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                    .Apply
                End With
            End If
        End With
        
        MsgBox n & " Duplicates found in " & ws.Name, vbInformation
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much @CDP1802

Answer (score 0):

You should add comparing the values of ranges

```
Sub sbFindDuplicatesInColumn()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim matchFoundIndex As Long
    Dim iCntr As Long
    lastRow = Range("A1:C").End(xlUp).Row

    For iCntr = 1 To lastRow
    If Cells(iCntr, 1) <> "" Then
        matchFoundIndex = WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(iCntr, 1), Range("A1:A" & lastRow), 0)
        If iCntr <> matchFoundIndex AND Cells(iCntr,1).Value <> Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Value
Then
            Cells(iCntr, 2) = "Duplicate" 
       End If
    End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `lastRow = Range("A1:C").End(xlUp).Row` gives a runtime error 1004